# is it possible to use xml-db as database on jsf

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-xml-db-repository

I am planning to create an application using JSF and mysql and xml db as database.

I am planning to use [exist-db](http://exist-db.org/) as database.

Is it possible to use xml db on jsf?

if yes, how?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application the JSF View components will be used in Screen rendering(View)

All the request parameters will come to JSF Backing Bean which is a controller here.

And MySql or XML Database related work will be in Model Layer.

So as long as XML Database Specific Java Api is available for communication with eXist-db you can integrate that in model layer of your application.

You can have help in

http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_xmldb.xml

So in Model Layer of your JSF based Java EE application you can integrate it easily.

Comment: thnks. it's really helpful. i'll use this one.